# Uso comercial de Visual Studio COMMUNITY, ASP.NET CORE y XAMARIN

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, asp.net-core, angular6, licencias

Un amigo y yo queremos llevar a cabo una idea. Queremos crear un sitio web (Angular), una app Xamarin y construir una web api en .NET CORE con este fin. Para el desarrollo vamos a utilizar VS 2019 COMMUNITY, hemos leído un poco los términos de la licencia, pero nos han surgido unas dudas respecto a si podemos comercializar lo que hagamos si utilizamos .net Core.

- Por ejemplo, en el caso de la Web API, ¿Podre publicarla en Azure (o en cualquier otro hosting) sin problema?
- En el caso de XAMARIN, ¿Podre publicar sin problema en la Play Store?
- En la licencia dice que hay un límite de usuarios (solo 5 usuarios) que pueden utilizar el software, pero no me queda claro si se refiere al número de programadores que pueden utilizar VS o a los usuarios finales.

En fin, ojalá puedan ayudarme y si algunos de ustedes hay tenido un caso similar me gustaría que contaran su experiencia.

Comment: Tene en cuenta que aca no hay abogados, y por lo tanto todo lo que te contesten carece de valor legal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el caso del web **Api** puedes publicarle en **azure** sin problemas mientras no rebases los costos "gratuitos" que te ofrecen, puedes usarlos en producción.
En cuanto a otros **hosting**, siempre y cuando el hosting soporte la tecnología con la que estas creando tu app.

- [azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/free-account-faq/)

En el caso de la **Playstore**, hay que pagar una licencia anual para poder publicar apps.
Para esto debes de crear una cuenta, pagar el precio y publicar tu **app**, es muy sencilla la publicación, solamente necesitas tu aplicación, algunas capturas de imagen, descripciones y llenar un cuestionario.

- [Play Store](https://play.google.com/intl/all_es/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html)
  https://developer.android.com/distribute/console

En el caso de **visual studio community** se refiere al número de programadores.

Al igual como consejo puedes usar **Azure DevOps** para la colaboración en equipo, repositorios, etc...

- [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/)

También hay una herramienta para publicar aplicaciones móviles por parte de **Microsoft** que se asocia con **azuredevops**, aunque un poco compleja de configurar.

- [Herramienta de publicación de apps](https://appcenter.ms/)

Comment: Gracias por responder Guasy, leí lo que ofrece azure, hay muchas opciones para escoger. ¿Tienes idea de cual seria la configuación basica para montar un proyecto pequeño (poco tráfico, no es necesario una gran cantidad de almacenamiento ni en bd ni en disco?

Comment: Ahi mismo te da las opciones, puedes agarrar las opciones mas basicas. Y acuerdate que la magia de la nube es que puedes ponerle mas memoria, mas ancho de banda o mas cpu cuando quieras dependiendo de como va creciendo la necesidad

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde tengo entendido (Y creo estar muy seguro de ello), el licenciamiento de Visual Studio (En cualquiera de sus sabores), no afecta para nada el licenciamiento/propiedad intelectual de los productos que desarrolles con este IDE.

En tu escenario, si son solo 2 personas (o hasta 5), puedes utilizar sin problema VS Community.

Si es para **dotnet Core**, puedes utilizar un IDE alternativo:

- VS Code
- Rider
- Atom, etc.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Camilo, entonces no habria problema alguno para comercializar mi proyecto.